# Using a variable in an Excel formula

Tags: excel

I currently have this formula: `=SUM(H11:H61)`
But i would like to make the 61 a variable, so for example the input in cell `A = 30`

then it would be like `=sum(H11:H(A1))`

But this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an FYI INDIRECT is volatile and if overused will slow down the calculation times.

Here is a non volatile version:

```
=SUM(H11:INDEX(H:H,A1))
```

This deals with if A1 is text by @Jeeped.

```
=SUM(H11:INDEX(H:H,MAX(11,A1))
```

Comment: Well, at least someone is listening to my nonsense.

Comment: `=SUM(H11:INDEX(H:H, MAX(11, A1)))`

Comment: @Jeeped only way to learn is listen to those that are smarter than we are.

Comment: @Jeeped maybe the OP wants to go the other way, it works if you put 1 in A1 it just sums H1:H11. :)  But yeah that would be something the OP should consider.

Comment: Well, he/she stated they wanted '*to make the 61 a variable*' so I inferred a forward or downward sum. The MAX was just to avoid an error if A1 was unintentionally blank. But yes, they could actually address the sum range backwards.

Comment: If it is left blank it would sum the entire column, I think.

Comment: Did I say *blank*? I meant text.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are looking for is `INDIRECT`. Here's one way of doing this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("H11:H"&A1))
```